# How to update variable value to current value (current value * 100/ colsums())

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df like below.:

[image]

I would like to do following two steps:

1. if first letter of col name matched the value in  `Grade` and current value is NA, then replace it as 0.
2. update the value from A1:B2 as current value, (`current value * 100/ colsums()`).

How can I make this happen?

```
df <- structure(list(Grade = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), Pass = c("Y", "N", 
"Y", "N"), A1 = c(7, 8, NA, NA), A2 = c(4, 5, NA, NA), A3 = c(9, 
NA, NA, NA), B1 = c(NA, NA, 8, NA), B2 = c(NA, NA, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `dplyr` package, we can use `across` with `case_when` (check my [old edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76403062/3) if you want to use two separate `ifelse`).

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(across(A1:B2, ~case_when(str_extract(cur_column(), "^.") == Grade & is.na(.x) ~ "0 (0%)",
                                  is.na(.x) ~ NA,
                                  .default = paste0(.x, " (", round(.x * 100/(sum(.x, na.rm = T)), digits = 2), "%)"))))

# A tibble: 4 × 7
  Grade Pass  A1         A2         A3       B1       B2        
  <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     
1 A     Y     7 (46.67%) 4 (44.44%) 9 (100%) NA       NA        
2 A     N     8 (53.33%) 5 (55.56%) 0 (0%)   NA       NA        
3 B     Y     NA         NA         NA       8 (100%) 3 (42.86%)
4 B     N     NA         NA         NA       0 (0%)   4 (57.14%)
```

---

#### Update

You need to first `pick` the columns if you want to use `colnames`.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(A1:B2, ~ifelse(str_extract(colnames(pick(.x)), "^.") == Grade & is.na(.x), 0, .x)), 
         across(A1:B2, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), NA, paste0(.x, " (", round(.x * 100/(sum(.x, na.rm = T)), digits = 2), "%)"))))
```

Comment: Will it be possible to refer the col name using other method, such as `colNames`, etc.? Could you show me more ways? Many thanks.

Comment: may I ask which package I should load for `pick`? got error message `could not find function "pick"
Caused by error in `pick()`:
! could not find function "pick"`

Comment: @Stataq It's from `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0 (current `dplyr` version is 1.1.2)

Comment: mine is 1.0.6 

Comment: @Stataq Well then you have not updated your packages for two years. There're a bunch of new features in `dplyr` version 1.1.0, I guess you should update now

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with two pivots:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Grade, Pass)) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(Grade == substring(name, 1, 1), coalesce(value, 0), value)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(is.na(value), "", sprintf("%i (%0.02f%%)", value, 100 * value / sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
  pivot_wider()
# # A tibble: 4 × 7
#   Grade Pass  A1           A2           A3            B1            B2          
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>         <chr>         <chr>       
# 1 A     Y     "7 (46.67%)" "4 (44.44%)" "9 (100.00%)" ""            ""          
# 2 A     N     "8 (53.33%)" "5 (55.56%)" "0 (0.00%)"   ""            ""          
# 3 B     Y     ""           ""           ""            "8 (100.00%)" "3 (42.86%)"
# 4 B     N     ""           ""           ""            "0 (0.00%)"   "4 (57.14%)"
```

Comment: @Stataq, updated to add the literal string formats